# Foreign key of one table primary key of another and vice versa

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

How to create an sql query for 2 tables with X(a)PK ==> Y(a)FK and X(b)FK <== Y(b)PK.Is it a good approach to do like that,

https://ibb.co/XDymWr7

This image explains the relation in more deapth.

I tried  with phpmyadmin. but landed clueless after some time.If this is a blunder question please excuse me.

Comment: Creating a circular  dependency never seems a good idea.

Comment: Potential inconsistency. Nothing prevents a project to refer to a variation which refers to another project.

Comment: @P.Salmon is there some triicks by which i can go about with this design and create two forms for data updaion through php.Can you give me some hints if it is possible.My senior designed this uml for me.

Comment: What do you want to model? One project related to many variations, and also a variation related to many models? If that's the case a relation table can be simpler.

Comment: @TheImpaler can you please help me by just guiding me by adding more about that.

Comment: First of all, it can work as you say but it's a bit cumbersome. Having a relation table models something a bit different. It all depends on what you want to model. Can you provide a few rows of sample data?

Comment: this may be helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity#:~:text=An%20associative%20(or%20junction)%20table,to%20the%20individual%20data%20tables.